# The number of ways we can arrange the symbols and blanks is?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

$6$ symbols are transmitted through a communication channel. A total of $12$ blanks are to be inserted between the symbols with at least $2$ blanks between every pair of symbols. The number of ways we can arrange the symbols and blanks is?

My approach :- ways to arrange $6$ distinct symbols $= 6!$

Place $2$ blanks between each symbol, remaining blanks $= 2$

Now these $2$ blanks can be placed in any of $5$ places so $= 5*5= 25$ ways

Total ways $= 6!*25 = 18000$

But the answer given in $10800$

please someone tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: One thing to think about is that when placing your blanks, it's true you have 5 places you could place each, but you don't necessarily get a different pattern by placing these remaining two blanks differently because you can't tell the blanks apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, there are $6!$ ways to order the $6$ symbols.  Once you've chosen an ordering for the $6$ symbols, your arrangement is uniquely determined by the placement of the $2$ extra blanks (which we assume are indistinguishable from one another) among the $5$ possible locations.  This is a stars-and-bars problem and there are $15 = \binom{2+5-1}{2}$ ways to place the blanks.  There are therefore $15 \cdot 720= 10,800$ possible arrangements.

Your answer is mistaken because you are double-counting any arrangement where the two extra blanks go into two different slots.  In other words, if one of the extra blanks is between the first two symbols and the other extra blank is between the last two symbols, you're counting that arrangement twice.

Comment: Robert is using [Theorem 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) on the linked page.